# External Provider Login in ASP Core, Identity Server 4 and Angular 2

Tags: asp.net, angular, oauth-2.0, .net-core, identityserver4

I have an ASP Core App setup with Identity Server 4 that provides token based authentication for an Angular 2 SPA.

To Login, username and password is sent via a Http Post to the "/connect" endpoint of identity server.

I want to extend the login process to include External Providers (Google, Facebook & all) but all the resources i can find online speak of an "Account Controller" which is inside of an MVC app, which i do not have.

I have been able to setup the client side of this process (retrieve the id_token of a user from Google, on the Angular SPA), but i don't know how to continue .

Where do i send the Oauth id_token ? Do i use the Extension Grants ? How ?

Please note that i do not have an "Account Controller" Class, the login flow is done by Identity Server and the JWT is returned to the angular app. I need guidance or advice on how to take the Oauth id_token, gotten from External Providers like Google, send it to the ASP core backend and create a user for that id_token, so when next the user logs into the app from Google, the User object (Apllication User) is fetched for him.

My setup can be found at this repo : https://github.com/robisim74/AngularSPAWebAPI

Answer (score 0):

For external providers you need the so called "implicit flow" - that's how it works. Check the quick start:

https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/release/quickstarts/4_external_authentication.html